# What are the differences between the Wooden Award and the Naismith Award?

Tags: basketball, collegiate, awards

College basketball has two primary "player of the year" awards: the [Wooden Award](http://www.woodenaward.com/) and the [Naismith Award](http://www.naismithawards.com/).

The Wooden Award is "[presented annually to the outstanding collegiate basketball Player of the Year.](http://www.woodenaward.com/?page_id=2)"

The Naismith Award is "[awarded annually to the women's and men's college basketball players of the year.](http://www.naismithawards.com/History/HistoryofNaismithTrophy.aspx)"

What are the differences between the Wooden Award and the Naismith Award?

Comment: look like asking the difference between the oscar and the golden globe. The q doesn't look bad, but looks trivial.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no differences apart from the very minor (number of winners, spelling). It seems that the actual point of the awards is identical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both awards represent the same thing: Player of the Year.

The difference lies in who gives out the award. The John R. Wooden award is handed out by the Los Angeles Athletic Club. The Naismith College Player of the Year award is given by the Atlanta Tipoff Club. There are plenty more awards with similar titles. The Associated Press College Basketball Player of the Year award (voted on by the AP themselves), The Adolph F. Rupp Trophy (given by the Commonwealth Athletic Club of Kentucky), the NABC (National Association of Basketball Coaches) award, and the Oscar Robertson Trophy (given by the United States Basketball Writers Association).

All of these trophies/awards symbolize the same thing, but are awarded by different entities. Therein lies your difference.